# Converting ULARGE_INTEGER QuadPart in to millisecond

Tags: c++, winapi

I found this code int the net.
I need to convert time in to millisecond.I am not able find out what QuadPart represent.Is this value is in Millisecond or nanosecond ..

Help me convert QuadPart values in to millisecond.

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);

FILETIME ft;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);  // converts to file time format
ULARGE_INTEGER ui;
ui.LowPart=ft.dwLowDateTime;
ui.HighPart=ft.dwHighDateTime;

// ui.QuadPart;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the current time (in milliseconds) from the system clock in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695288/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-from-the-system-clock-in-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ui.QuadPart` would be the amount of 100-nanosecond ticks since January 1, 1601 (UTC). To get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1601 (UTC) divide it by 10000.

See documentation for the [FILETIME structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx).