# Convert 100-nanoseconds to millisecond confusion

Tags: c++, windows, time, filetime

**NOTE:** This is likely a question about flawed math, rather then a question
about the a windows system call as described in the question.

We are working with with the `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` win32 call, and seeing what I think are strange results and was looking for some clarification. From MSDN on the FILETIME structure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

According to our read of this description, the value returned is the number of **10e-8** interval seconds. Assuming this is correct, then the following function should return the system time in milliseconds.

```
DWORD get_milli_time() {
    FILETIME f;
    ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&f);
    __int64 nano = (__int64(f.dwHighDateTime) << 32LL)
                  + __int64(f.dwLowDateTime);
    return DWORD(nano / 10e5);
    }
```

A simple unittest however shows this is incorrect, the below code prints "Failed":

```
DWORD start = get_milli_time();
::Sleep(5000);  // sleep for 5-seconds
DWORD end = get_milli_time();
// test for reasonable sleep variance (4.9 - 5.1 secs)
if ((end - start) < 4900 || (end - start) > 5100) {
    printf("Failed\n");
    }
```

According to this SO post
[Getting the current time (in milliseconds) from the system clock in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695288/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-from-the-system-clock-in-windows),
the correct results can be achieved by changing our division to:

```
return DWORD(nano / 10e3);
```

If we use this value, we get the correct result, but I can't understand why.

It seems to me that to convert from **10e-8** to **10e-3**, we should divide by **10e5**. This would seem to be borne out by the following calculation:

```
printf("%f\n", log10(10e-3 / 10e-8));
```

Which returns 5 (as I expected).

But somehow I'm wrong -- but I'll be darned if I can see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Have you tried calling `get_milli_time()` twice, about 5 seconds apart, and looking at the values it gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your math is indeed flawed, and so is your understanding of the "working" code.

There are 10<sup>7</sup> 100-nanosecond intervals in a second, 10<sup>4</sup> in a millisecond.  In floating-point notation, this is `1.0e4`.  `10e3` is a weird way of writing `1e4`.

The "right" (in a sense of most efficient while remaining expressive) code would be

```
return DWORD(hundrednano * 1.0e-4);
```

Comment: Maybe a notation mistake. `10^3` with `10e3` when it actually is `10^3 = 1e3`

Comment: @Nacho: Not maybe, definitely.

Comment: My mistake was incorrect *e* scientific notation. Thanks.