# C++11 print current system time (including milliseconds)

Tags: c++

I wish to print the current (local) time (based on say `std::chrono::system_clock`) whilst including milliseconds, e.g. `12:32:45.287`. 
I can do it without milliseconds, with:

```
std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
char buffer[sizeof("HH:MM:SS")];
if (std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&time)) == 0)
    std::cout << "Error formating time" << std::endl;
else std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

It would also be good if I could get an integer number of milliseconds. (I can get seconds with `std::localtime(&time)->tm_sec`)

**EDIT** I would like a portable solution, but if that's not possible, than one that works with Windows 10/Visual C++ 14.0/Intel Compiler 16.0

Answer (score 0):

You can get milliseconds by this timeval if you use linux or unix.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

long getCurrentTime() {
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
   return tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
}

int main() {
    cout<<"milliseconds: "<<getCurrentTime()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my system does not have a `sys/time.h` header file

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes (Windows 10/Visual C++ 14/Intel Compiler 16.0)

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695288/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-from-the-system-clock-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it portably in C then look at what the portable libraries are using ie Apache APR...

https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__time.html

Or applications written in C that are ported to the platforms you want to target ie Mysql, Lua, JVM