# Get time in milliseconds on Windows

Tags: c, windows, random, time

I need a way to get the time in a high precision (milliseconds or microseconds) for a PRNG algorithm I'm writing in C (C11), as `time(0)` is not precise enough.

I tried using several other possible solutions, which I found on StackOverflow, but none of them worked for me.

Anyways my problem is now fixed, with the help of the code @dbush provided

Comment: What did you try, and what about them did not work for you?

Comment: For Win32 you can use `GetTickCount64()`.

Comment: @Scott Hunter Technically all of them worked, but I would always get 0 as a time difference, due to my program running too quickly

Comment: Normally, you'd get time and seed your PRNG once at the start of your program, not repeatedly. Or is the process stopping and starting multiple times per second?

Comment: @Ruud Helderman My PRNG works a bit differently, as I have a ```randint``` function, which generates a random integer based of the elapsed time

Comment: ChaoticSomeone, "on Windows" --> It is a compiler issue, not an OS one.  What compiler?

Comment: Please consider not reinventing PRNGs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the current time (in milliseconds) from the system clock in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695288/getting-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-from-the-system-clock-in-windows)

Comment: @van dech my problem has already been solved. Thanks anyways

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I suspect OP's interest in high precision time is not reinventing PRNG, but seeding it.

Comment: ChaoticSomeone, you appear now to have a way to get a high precision time, yet how you use it for a PRNG may be questionable.  Yet since that use is not posted, the real issue is not truly well solved.

Comment: From the comment: "I have a randint function, which generates a random integer based of the elapsed time". Looks like it's not just a seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` function, which gives you the current time in 100ns intervals since 1/1/1601 UTC.

```
FILETIME ft;
uint64_t ts;
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);

ts = 0;
ts |= ft.dwHighDateTime;
ts <<= 32;
ts |= ft.dwLowDateTime;
```

Note that the system clock is most likely not that precise, so don't expect 100ns granularity.

Another option is `QueryPerformanceCounter`, which will give you microsecond intervals from an undetermined starting point:

```
LARGE_INTEGER ticks;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&ticks);
uint64_t ts = ticks.QuadPart;
```

Comment: How is ```uint64_t``` a datatype? I get the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'uint64_t'

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone You'll need to `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: Now I don't get an error but I still get the same results in my for-loop

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone Try both options, and try printing the resulting vaule to see how much it changes between invocations.

Comment: what format specifier is it for ```uint64_t```?

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone `%I64u`

Comment: my results are: 133203440785961221(called before the loop), 5219627056065(called after the loop)

Comment: As of now I got my program to generate random numbers using the 2 code snippets provided by you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `"%"PRIu64` is standard and portable (from `inttypes.h`).

Comment: If possible, it would seem better to use `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` which should have greater precision (<1us according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime)) than `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from C11, you can use `struct timespec` and `timespec_get` to get the same value as `time(NULL)` in seconds and nanoseconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    printf("Time since epoch: %ld seconds, %ld nanoseconds", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
}
```

Comment: This code just raises an error

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone can you tell what exactly the error is? I have tested and the program seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Call to undeclared function 'timespec_get'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'TIME_UTC'

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone the only explanation I can think of is that your compiler doesn't fully conform with C11. Can you tell what compiler you're using and the version?

Comment: Don't know about what compiler I'm using, I don't even know where to find that out, but in my CMakeLists it says version 3.23

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone are you using Visual Studio? If not then I'm assuming you're using MinGW.

Comment: I use CLion as my IDE

Comment: @ChaoticSomeone I'm fairly CLion only partially supports C11, and from what I can tell that doesn't include the C11 time utilities. If you want to use C11 fully and properly, you may want to switch.

Comment: I will consider switching to a different IDE